# Mysterious, unattributed things observed in DevTools profiling - what is this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling, devtools

I was profiling my app for performance, when I started to notice something strange. A 'mousemove' event was firing and calling code I hadn't added myself. Heck, I don't have a mousemove listener on my page. I thought it might be an extension, maybe AdBlock, so I disabled all of my extensions. It didn't go away.

Also, upon opening a `<select>` list, I noticed it calling some class 'ListPicker'... Seriously, no clue where this is coming from. Some screenshots:

[image]

Also notice the "Compile Script"... I'm not eval-ing any script on my page by default. What gives? Looking for the source, DevTools simply says this:
[image]

Can I somehow **still** make DevTools redirect me to the exact lines of code it was executing? It is frustrating to see strange, alien code executed on one's page and not even being able to look at the source code.

More on the mousemove events it was firing:
[image]

Upon inspecting the sources tab, I found nothing but my own files.
[image]

In addition, I noticed that always somewhere towards the end of my profiling session, this "unattributed" source would appear to be completely blocking my JavaScript:
[image]

HOWEVER, this is not even what happens. My site stays completely responsive - it wouldn't do that with 100% scripting CPU usage. However DevTools says otherwise. The last thing that really gave me nightmares was this:

[image]

**NEGATIVE SCRIPTING TIME?** You can even see Chrome's rendering giving up towards the left of that pie chart.

So, in all my confusion, what exactly could this be? How do I find the source of this, or does it even have one, maybe this is just a bug within the newest version of Chrome? Really appreciate if anyone could drop their thoughts.

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can file one at crbug.com
Please attach the recorded performance profile.